# Boot Failure from USB Flash Drive after Changed Boot Order

Tags: installation, live-usb

I have live ubuntu 12.04 desktop on a usb flash drive. I've gone into my BIOS and changed the boot order so that it runs external drives first. On startup, when the flash is in, it will start to boot it. But, it doesn't do anything but give this message:

```
SYSLINUX 4.06 EDD 2012-10-23 Copyright (C) 1994-2012 H. Peter Anvin et al_
```

The underscore just flashes. I don't know what to do from here. I've attempted every key and each key combination I can think of. It doesn't appear to respond to keys at all. 
The flash drive is formatted in FAT32, by the way.

I used Universal USB Installer to put it on there.

Comment: You should try to make your `USB` bootable again. It would not be successful. I recommend you to make `Bootable USB` by using `Startup Disk Creator`, for this you may have to refer someone who has Ubuntu installed or `Ubuntu Live Disk`.

Comment: Just a word of advise: Please try to add the actual question into the headline, if possible. "What do i do now?" is not very descriptive. And try to keep your description of the problem as short and to-the-point as possible. Add what you've done, where it went wrong and any information you think will be useful to know, when helping you solve the problem. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It would be helpful if you edited your question and added how you created the bootable USB. Fat32 is alright, btw :)

Comment: Would it be something where I can press a certain key combination when that appears or something where I'd be better off trying again, possibly with another bootable USB creator?

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

You could start with this:

- Make sure the ISO file you have downloaded is healty ([HOWTO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)). If it's not healty, download it again.
- If the ISO is healty, try to switch to another burning program, like [uNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).
- If it still won't boot, try to boot the live USB on another computer, or try to install the ISO on another USB, if possible.
- You could also burn the ISO file to a CD/DVD and boot from that.
- Some USB sticks (Sandisk) come with firmware called U3, that will prevent USB booting of Ubuntu from working. [U3 Launchpad Removal Tool](http://u3.sandisk.com/launchpadremoval.htm)

If it still does'nt work, let us know and we will try to help you! Good luck!

*Several of these suggestions were gathered from other answers on Ask Ubuntu. Thanks!*